# DBeaver localhost PostgreSQL connection refused

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, dbeaver

I just installed DBeaver on my personal computer and am trying to create a PostgreSQL database.

I entered the following in the Connect to database window:

- Host: localhost
- Port: 5432
- Database: postgres
- User: postgres

Those values were all pre-filled defaults, so I left them and clicked the Test Connection... button.

When I click the Test button an error window opens, saying, "Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. Connection refused: connect"

I tried setting my own db name and credentials, but get the same results.

How do I set up a local PostgreSQL database in DBeaver?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DBeaver does not allow to setup a local PostgreSQL server or instance: it allows to connect to an **existing** server or instance. If the PostgreSQL instance does not exist you should install PostgreSQL binaries and create a new database instance with `initdb`.

Answer (score 3):

If your operating system is Windows 10 Home, you have to use `192.168.99.100` instead of `localhost`.

Answer (score 3):

Answer from here - https://www.reddit.com/r/dbeaver/comments/fi8h0q/new_dbeaver_install_how_to_set_up_first/.

Dbeaver is just a client to the server. You need to setup the server itself first.

https://www.postgresql.org/

Download and setup the server then you can connect to it with DBeaver and do what you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same, and then I remembered that I didn't start postgres with the script